# How to determine dictionary root header

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, xcode, nsxmlparser

will like to know how do i determine dictionary root header, i will scan a QR code to get a link which will then convert the xml into a dictionary. i need to determine the header `<image>` or `<audio>`
as i need to retrieve differ data from them.

thanks for the feedback.

i have this 2 XML

```
<image>
<postID>999</postID>
<title>picture question</title> 
  <question>What is that?</question>
  <hint></hint>
  <content>http://test.com/download.jpg</content>
  <direction>Right</direction>
  <answer1>a</answer1>
  <answer2>b</answer2>
  <answer3>c</answer3>
  <answer4>d</answer4>
  <correctAnswer>b</correctAnswer>
  <score>10</score>
</image>



<audio>     
<postID>333</postID>         
<title>audio question</title>        
<question>Who is talking?</question> 
  <hint></hint>
<content>http://test.com/autobots.mp4"</content>   
<direction>Up</direction>   
<answer1>1</answer1>   
<answer2>2</answer2>   
<answer3>3</answer3>   
<answer4>4</answer4> 
  <correctAnswer>2</correctAnswer>   
<score>40</score> </audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [AllKeys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Or

Check the valueForKey: method and test the response for both "image" & "audio". If its nil for one then go with the other key.

Answer (score 1):

The `[dictionary allKeys]` will return your root keys as an array.

It works for me.

Hope it works for you too.